# Y axis labels with power of ten only at the end of the axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting some time series with ggplot2. The values on the y axis are very small (0.000000043). I am trying to reduce the number of digits so it looks nicer. I want to have 3 different values on the y axis (min,max and median). If I round up (e.g. with 3 decimal points) the values then all these 3 numbers turn to zero.

What I have made so far is:

```
g<- g + scale_y_continuous(breaks = y_values,label= function(x) {ifelse(x==0, "0", parse(text=gsub("[+]", "", gsub("e", " %*% 10^", scientific_format()(x)))))} )
```

This will create values of the form 43x10^-9.

I would like to have only 43 on the tick and the 10^-9 to be on the very top of the y axis. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not multiply the y variable by 10^9 then do "y values ( x 10^-9)" as the axis title?

Comment: I might try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can alias the axis tick labels to be anything you want and then use `annotate()` to put a text label anywhere you want:

```
g + scale_y_continuous(breaks = y_values, labels = y_values * 1e9) +
    annotate("text", 
             x = -0.5,                 # or whatever you need it to be
             y = 50e-9,                # or whatever you need it to be
             label = "*10^-9")
```

Comment: Yes, this works quite well. The only problem is that I have 15 different panels in a figure and annotate will have to be fixed for each panel automatically, which will take a lot of time.